# JavaScript, how to change id based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

Basically, I'm testing code for my Arduino by using JavaScript. What I want to do (on the Arduino) is to click a button (+) to change the screen (there are 8 screens, 0 indexed). What actually happens is that you click the button, which increments a variable, this variable then controls what screen is 'activated'. When the variable is equal to 7, the next press changes it to 0. There is also a (-) button which does the opposite.

The above is what I want to achieve on my Arduino LCD. However, I'm writing it in JavaScript just to test logic etc.

Here's my current code:

```
<p id='cool'></p>
<button id='plus' onclick='plus(); check()'>+</button>
<button id='sub' onclick='sub(); check()'>-</button>    
<br>
<p id='show'></p>

<script>

    var cool = document.getElementById('cool');
    var status = 0;

    function plus(){

        if(status == 7){
            status = 0;
        }else{
            status++;
        }

        cool.innerHTML = status;
    }

    function sub(){

        if(status == 0){
            status = 7;
        }else{
            status--;
        }

        cool.innerHTML = status;
    }

</script>
```

The `cool` id simply displays the status.

I would like to change the contents of the show id depending on the value of the status. I originally had though to use a switch statement, like:

```
function check(){
    switch(status){
        case 0:
        document.getElementById('show') = "one";
        break;
        case 1:
        document.getElementById('show') = "two";
        break;
        default:
        document.getElementById('show') = "default";
    }
}
```

You will notice the `check()` function is already in the `onclick` for the buttons.

Unfortunately, this method has not worked for me, any ideas why?

Comment: `document.getElementById('show').innerHTML="one"` seems to be what you want

Comment: OR perhaps `document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=["zero","one","two",...,"seven"][status]`

Comment: @mplungjan Agreed, that array shortcut is so useful.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, that's worked fantastic, how does the joint arrray work? I assume the [status] is switching it out?

Comment: @N.Sainsbury It might be clearer if you assign the array to a variable: `allStatuses = ["zero","one","two",...,"seven"]`. Now `document.getElementById('show').innerHTML= allStatuses[status]` is the same as mplungjan's suggestion.

Comment: I prefer `document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "zero one two three four five six seven".split(/\s/) [status];` as it's a bit easier to change

Comment: @zfrisch And much harder to read.

Comment: @N.Sainsbury Yes, as the other comments show it is just a shorthand for declaring the array and then later using it. You could declare the screen array outside the function to not have the browser declare it very time

Comment: @mplungjan & Code-Apprentice thanks for the help, it is very greatly appreciated. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to upvote the answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Not really to me. Put the split() and `[status]` on separate lines and it's not too difficult, but that's imo obviously.

Comment: @zfrisch Would you have understood that line of code the first month that you learned JavaScript?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think you're looking too deep into it. I like it because it's easier to add to, and the first month I used JavaScript was circa 2003 when JS clocks/tic-tac-toe/page counters were all the rage, so I have zero idea, but that wasn't the point.

Comment: @zfrisch Thank you for your opinion. My primary objection to the readability is the use of regexes. These are very confusing to beginner programmers. For me readability is incredibly important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('show').innerHTML="one"` seems to be what you want –

OR perhaps

```
document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=["zero","one","two",...,"seven"][status]
```

Here is a complete example - please note that the snippet wraps all this in "window.onload" type event handler. You would need to put the script before the `</body>` to get the same effect without the onload

```js
var screens = [
  "Screen 1",
  "Screen 2",
  "Screen 3",
  "Screen 4",
  "Screen 5",
  "Screen 6",
  "Screen 7",
  "Screen 8"
];

var cool = document.getElementById('cool');
var show = document.getElementById('show');
var status = 0;

function plus() {

  if (status == 7) {
    status = 0;
  } else {
    status++;
  }

  cool.innerHTML = status;
}

function sub() {

  if (status == 0) {
    status = 7;
  } else {
    status--;
  }
}  
function check() {
  cool.innerHTML = status;
  show.innerHTML = screens[status];
}
check(); // show the first screen (status = 0)
```

```html
<p id='cool'></p>
<button id='plus' onclick='plus(); check()'>+</button>
<button id='sub' onclick='sub(); check()'>-</button>
<br>
<p id='show'></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm very happy with it! Just a quick question - why did you do the check(); at the end? Would it not naturally run when buttons are clicked?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to show screen 1 when the page loaded

Comment: PS:  `if (status == 7)` can be written more generic as `if (status >= screens.length)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "has not worked for me". Please consider the following:
In your switch statement, you are checking the value of "status", essentially if there is a value for "status" do something. However, in JavaScript the value numeric 0 is a falsy value. So your switch condition will never be met when the value is 0. Again, 0 is the same as false (or null) but your switch gets executed only when there is a value and 0 is not considered a value.
Try using something like:

```
switch(status || status === 0){
...
}
```

Also, I would call the "check() function from "plus" and "sub" functions directly.

One more thing, the following:

```
document.getElementById('show') = "one"
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById('show').innerText = "one"
```

or

```
document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "one"
```

Same applies to similar statements.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Cool...sorry I was typing the answer and didn't see yours. Cheers!